# sklearn.externals module description

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I could not find any description about the `sklearn.externals` module in scikit-learn.
Does anybody knows what is this module for?

And what is sklearn.externals.six.moves doing exactly?

Answer (score 3):

You can see a readme on that module's [Github page](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/tree/master/sklearn/externals).  It says:

> This directory contains bundled external dependencies that are updated every once in a while.

In other words, the code in there is not really part of scikit, it's just other libraries that scikit uses, but it stores its own copies of them inside itself to avoid dependency problems if the user has different versions installed.

Answer (score 1):

> And what is sklearn.externals.six.moves doing exactly?

*Nothing*. It is created in [`six.py`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/86b1ba72771718acbd1e07fbdc5caaf65ae65440/sklearn/externals/six.py) and populated via the [add_move()](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/86b1ba72771718acbd1e07fbdc5caaf65ae65440/sklearn/externals/six.py#L338) method, which is [never called](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=add_move). To check via command-line:

```
>>> from sklearn import externals
>>> externals.six.moves
<module 'sklearn.externals.six.moves' (built-in)>
>>> help(externals.six.moves)
# gives nothing, let's see its attributes and methods
>>> externals.six.moves.__dict__
{'__name__': 'sklearn.externals.six.moves', '__doc__': None}
```